# Options for temp file storage in web farm

Tags: c#, networking, file-upload, windows-authentication

We are moving to a web farm behind a load balancer.  I have an app that uploads an excel file, saves to apps_data folder in the app directory, uses LinqToExcel to do a bunch of processing, then deletes the file.  Because this is all done in one shot, do I need to make any changes?

If I do need to move, the other option is to save the file to the network share file server.  To do that, I would have to pass along the credentials for the folder access (network guys have set up permissions for the app so I can test it out).  I have been researching this option and it looks like the passing of creds makes it a huge pain.  Is anyone aware of a pre-existing library for this operation?  If not, is there a good test out there I can read? All I have found so far is just bits and pieces.